# How do you exclude the XML prolog from output?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I write `$xml = new DOMDocument();` and it automatically creates `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. I need to NOT create it. How do i do that?

One solution is to search the first ">" and strsub at the index at the first < found. But i like a nicer way to do this.

Comment: I needed this today I found a couple of similar questions (answered) here: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706086/php-domdocument-output-without-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947695/remove-xml-version-tag-when-a-xml-is-created-in-php/17362351#17362351 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260096/hide-xml-declaration-in-files-generated-using-php Each thread has a specific solution that could fit your needs.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate of another question - please flag it as such instead of adding an answer.

Answer (score 5):

When you `saveXML`, pass in the root element as the `node` argument. Only the root element and its contents will be serialised, and not any XML declaration, doctype, comments or PIs outside the root.

```
$doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
```

or, if you need the other stuff but just not the redundant declaration:

```
$result= '';
foreach($document->childNodes as $node)
    $result.= $document->saveXML($node)."\n";
```