# PHP DomDocument output without <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: php, domdocument

is there an option with DomDocument to remove the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The class instantiation automatically adds it to the output, but is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: `$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);`

Comment: You don't need navigate through childNodes, just save document root element: solution of @Tiberi-Ionut Stan.
;)

Comment: [`LIBXML_NOXMLDECL`](http://php.net/libxml.constants#constant.libxml-noxmldecl) ; see also [remove xml version tag when a xml is created in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5947695/367456)

Comment: `$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement)` excludes the XML declaration indeed, but does not keep the DTD, which is often very important (read IE). On the other side, the LIBXML_NOXMLDECL flag seems not to be supported yet, so the answer chosen seems to me a good compromise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to output HTML, use the `saveHTML()` function. It automatically avoids a whole lot of XML idiom and handles closed/unclosed HTML idiom properly.

If you want to output XML you can use the fact that `DOMDocument` is a `DOMNode` (namely: '/' in XPath expression), thus you can use `DOMNode` API calls on it to iterate over child nodes and call `saveXML()` on each child node. This does not output the XML declaration, and it outputs all other XML content properly.

Example:

```
$xml = get_my_document_object();
foreach ($xml->childNodes as $node) {
   echo $xml->saveXML($node);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will. (Btw, the OP would not have accepted the answer if it brutally mangled his output like that...) Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @user268396 yeah, you were right. That foreach is just a trick, and a well formed XML would only server one node to that foreach.

Comment: !This solution is not correct in my opinion. The correct one is @hrvoj3e (!)

Comment: @PeterKrauss try it with the following string and observe the differences in output: "<!DOCTYPE might-be-important><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='now-you-see-me-now-you-dont.xsl'?><root/>". Which one is correct, if all you want to do is remove the XML prolog?

Answer (score 37):

I think using DOMDocument is a universal solution for valid XML files:

If you have XML already loaded in a variable:

```
$t_xml = new DOMDocument();
$t_xml->loadXML($xml_as_string);
$xml_out = $t_xml->saveXML($t_xml->documentElement);
```

For XML file from disk:

```
$t_xml = new DOMDocument();
$t_xml->load($file_path_to_xml);
$xml_out = $t_xml->saveXML($t_xml->documentElement);
```

This comment helped: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#88525

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted one.  Take my +1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I am using `symfony/serializer` for XML creation. If you also want to achieve this with Symfony serializer you can do in this way:

```php
$encoder = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder();

$encoder->encode($nodes[$rootNodeName], 'xml', [
    XmlEncoder::ROOT_NODE_NAME => $rootNodeName,
    XmlEncoder::ENCODING       => $encoding,
    XmlEncoder::ENCODER_IGNORED_NODE_TYPES => [
          XML_PI_NODE, //this flag is the solution
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the answers above worked:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXXX('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content);  // loadXML or loadHTML
$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

The above didn't work for me if I had partial HTML, e.g.

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
```

As it then removed the everything after `<p>Lorem</p>`.

The only solution that worked for me was:

```
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $xx) {
    if ($xx instanceof \DOMProcessingInstruction) {
        $xx->parentNode->removeChild($xx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use output buffering to remove it. A bit of a hack but it works.

```
ob_start();

// dom stuff

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$clean = preg_replace("/(.+?\n)/","",$output);
```