# remove xml version tag when a xml is created in php

Tags: php, xml

I'm creating a xml using this

```
$customXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<abc></abc>');
```

after adding some attributes onto this, when I try to print it
it appears like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc id="332"><params><param name="aa">33</param></params></abc>
```

Is there a way to remove the xml version node ?
Thank you

Comment: the entire prolog or just the version information?

Comment: Why? It might be pointless, but it shouldn't do any harm.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In theory you can provide the [`LIBXML_NOXMLDECL` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) to drop the XML declaration when saving a document, but this is only available in Libxml >= 2.6.21 (and [buggy](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50989.)). An alternative would be to use

```
$customXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<abc></abc>');
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($customXML);
echo $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for perfect answer

Comment: Be careful, this is escaping non-ASCI characters to enitites.

Answer (score 17):

I have a simmilar solution to the accepted answer:

If you have xml allready loaded in a variable:

```
$t_xml = new DOMDocument();
$t_xml->loadXML($xml_as_string);
$xml_out = $t_xml->saveXML($t_xml->documentElement);
```

For XML file from disk:

```
$t_xml = new DOMDocument();
$t_xml->load($file_path_to_xml);
$xml_out = $t_xml->saveXML($t_xml->documentElement);
```

This comment helped: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#88525

Answer (score 13):

A practical solution: you know that the first occurrence of `?>` in the result string is going to be then end of the xml version substring. So:

```
$customXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<abc></abc>');
$customXML = substr($customXML, strpos($customXML, '?'.'>') + 2);
```

Note that `?>` is split into two parts because otherwise some poor syntax highlighter may have problems parsing at this point.

Answer (score 7):

As `SimpleXMLElement` always uses `"\n"` to separate the XML-Declaration from the rest of the document, it can be split at that position and the remainder taken:

```
explode("\n", $customXML->asXML(), 2)[1];
```

Example:

```
<?php

$customXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<!-- some comment -->
<abc>
</abc>');

echo explode("\n", $customXML->asXML(), 2)[1];
```

Output:

```
<!-- some comment -->
<abc>
</abc>
```

Answer (score 6):

There's another way without the replacing xml header. I prefer this:

```
$xml = new xmlWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startElement('abc');
$xml->writeAttribute('id', 332);
$xml->startElement('params');
$xml->startElement('param');
$xml->writeAttribute('name', 'aa');
$xml->text('33');
$xml->endElement();
$xml->endElement();
echo $xml->outputMemory(true);
```

Gives output:

```
<abc id="332"><params><param name="aa">33</param></params></abc>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Try:**

```
$xmlString = $doc->saveXML();
$xmlString = str_replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n", '', $xmlString);
file_put_contents($filename, $xmlString);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace("/<\\?xml.*\\?>/",'',$doc->saveXML(),1);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm doing. My solution: `return preg_replace( "/<\?xml.+?\?>/", "", $doc->asXml() );`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem, this should do it:

```
$xml = str_replace(' version="1.0"', '', $xml);`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$customXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<source><abc>hello</abc></source>');
$result = $customXML->xpath('//abc');
$result = $result[0];
var_dump($result->asXML());
```

Answer (score -1):

XML header tags and PHP short tags are incompatible.  So, this may be an issue of using the short tags in PHP (i.e. `<?=` instead of `<?php echo...`).  So, turning off short tags in PHP.INI (and updating your code appropriately) may resolve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand.