# php simplexml without xml declaration tag

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I use SimpleXML to generate XML.
When I use :

```
new SimpleXMLElement('<row></row>');
```

SimpleXML generates this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<row/>
```

But I need only :

```
<row/>
```

I need only it because I will include it to another XML.

How can I generate only row tag in an SimpleXML Object ?

Answer (score 6):

As has been outlined in the earlier Q&A:

- [remove xml version tag when a xml is created in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5947695/367456)

You can import the **SimpleXMLElement** into the [*PHP Document Object Model (DOM) extension*](http://php.net/book.dom) and output it there as XML because that extension can output without the XML declaration.

Importing into dom works with the [`dom_import_simplexml`](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml) function.

Example:

```
$xml    = new SimpleXMLElement('<row></row>');
$domxml = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
echo $domxml->ownerDocument->saveXML($domxml->ownerDocument->documentElement);
```

Output:

```
<row/>
```

You can also run this code your own online here: https://eval.in/302096

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you but I want an SimpleXML object. I want be able to add child in this object.