# How to add an attribute to an XML Element in PHP without the xml header?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I need to add a new attribute to xml elements stored in DB. This is not a complete XML, but just XML elements in the DB.

When I do the following,

```
$node_xml = simplexml_load_string('<node name="nodeA">this is a node</node>');
$node_xml->addAttribute('newattrib', "attribA");
$res_xml = $node_xml->asXML();
```

I get `$res_xml` as:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<node name=\"nodeA\" newattrib=\"attribA\">this is a node</node>\n"
```

How do I eliminate the `<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>` part without doing a string manipulation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove xml version tag when a xml is created in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947695/remove-xml-version-tag-when-a-xml-is-created-in-php)

Comment: That question/answer doesn't deal with adding attribute.

Comment: @splash58 saw that. But cannot add an attribute there without string manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the root level and then get the node but not the full xml. In that case the header will not be echoed

```
$string = '<node name="nodeA">this is a node</node>';
$node_xml = simplexml_load_string('<root>'. $string .'</root>');
$node = $node_xml->children()[0];
$node->addAttribute('newattrib', "attribA");

echo $res_xml = $node->asXML(); // <node name="nodeA" newattrib="attribA">this is a node</node>
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/788541)**

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` for setting attribute in a tag.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domObject = new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML('<node name="nodeA">this is a node</node>',LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$result=$domObject->getElementsByTagName("node")->item(0);
$result->setAttribute("newattrib","attribA");
echo $result->ownerDocument->saveHTML();
```

**Output:** `<node name="nodeA" newattrib="attribA">this is a node</node>`