# Hide XML declaration in files generated using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I was tesing with a simple example of how to display XML in browser using PHP and found this example which works good

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$root = $xml->createElement("data");
$xml->appendChild($root); 
$id   = $xml->createElement("id");
$idText = $xml->createTextNode('1');
$id->appendChild($idText);
$title   = $xml->createElement("title");
$titleText = $xml->createTextNode('Valid');
$title->appendChild($titleText);
$book = $xml->createElement("book");
$book->appendChild($id);
$book->appendChild($title);
$root->appendChild($book);

$xml->formatOutput = true;
echo "<xmp>". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
$xml->save("mybooks.xml") or die("Error");
?>
```

It produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <book>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Valid</title>
  </book>
</data>
```

Now I have got two questions regarding how the output should look like.

1. The first line in the xml file '', should not be displayed, that is it should be hidden
2. How can I display the TextNode in the next line. In total I am exepecting an output in this fashion

   ```
   <data>
     <book>
       <id>1</id>
       <title>
         Valid
       </title>
     </book>
   </data>
   ```

Is that possible to get the desired output, if so how can I accomplish that.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you exclude the XML prolog from output?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527513/how-do-you-exclude-the-xml-prolog-from-output)

Answer (score 1):

To skip the XML declaration you can use the result of `saveXML` on the root node:

```
$xml_content = $xml->saveXML($root);
file_put_contents("mybooks.xml", $xml_content) or die("cannot save XML");
```

Please note that `saveXML(node)` has a different output from `saveXML()`.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**
here is my post where all usable threads with answers are listed: [How do you exclude the XML prolog from output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527513/how-do-you-exclude-the-xml-prolog-from-output/17362519#17362519)

**Second question:**
I don't know of any PHP function that outputs text nodes like that.

You could:

- read xml using DomDocument and save each node as string
- iterate trough nodes
- detect text nodes and add new lines to xml string manually

At the end you would have the same XML with text node values in new line:

```
<node>
    some text data
</node>
```